# Animações com css

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Olá, estou com uma duvida em relação a animações com css, eu tenho uma pagina feita em HTML para um sistema de Internet das Coisas, que quando o usuário clica na bebida o sistema manda uma requisição para um servidor que por sua vez manda para um arduino, mas para alem disto eu cria fazer um sistema que colocasse o icon da bebida a girar enquanto o arduino "fazia a bebida", mas não sei como fazer?

PS: eu em cada icon tenho um id que com jquery quando clicado eu consigo colocar e remover classes!

PS: A primeira imagem esta virada pois foi de uns testes que estive a fazer, mas sem sucesso!

[image: Pagina da Maquina]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie uma classe com `animation` vinculada ao `@keyframes` que irá girar o elemento 360 graus. Ao ser clicado, adicione a classe ao elemento para ativar o efeito:

```js
var wraps = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");
for(var x=0; x<wraps.length; x++){
   wraps[x].onclick = function(){
      this.classList.add("ativo");
   }
}
```

```css
.wrapper{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/gear_318-56262.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
   float: left;
}

.wrapper img{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.wrapper.ativo{
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear; /*velocidade de 1 segundo. Quanto maior, mais lento*/
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
Clique nas imagens:
<br>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```